# increment a counter under certain condition (ex: only if user didn't input wrong answer)

Tags: javascript, logic, counter, decision-tree

Right now,  the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvvboazr/) produces math questions and when user enters the right answer, the `correct` counter goes up. When the user enters the `wrong` answer the wrong counter goes up. I need help taking this a step further. If the user inputs the wrong answer the correct counter should not be able to increment ever for that question. they have to get the answer right to go to the next question but when they get it right the correct counter doesnt increment. only the wrong counter increments once for that question they got wrong.

I sometimes get stuck in figuring out this type of logic:

```
pseudo Code:
attempt = 0 //set originally to 0 since question was  attempted and answer was wrong

        if(answer is right && attempt 0){
            correct++
        }else if(answer is wrong){
            wrong++
            attempt = 1  //question was attempted and answer was wrong
            //this is where i get stuck. if i set attempt to 0 here it doesnt help
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: make the wrong also count only once per question.

The code can be written into:

```
    attempt = 0;

    if(answer is right){
      // First attempt is correct
      if (attempt === 0) {
        correct++
      }
      // go to next question, no matter the first try is correct or not.
      // set attempts back to 0, for a new question.
      attempt= 0;
    }else if(answer is wrong){
        // If we tried it, but wrong, then mark the answer wrong
        if (attempt === 0) {
           wrong++
        }
        attempt++
    }
```

And take a look of this logic on your altered [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvvboazr/4/)

Comment: Thanks. i like how the correct numbers are updating the way i want them to in the fiddle. if you could be so kind as to make it so that if the user keeps on entering the wrong answer it doesn't update the wrong count. it should only update the wrong count  once per question. and obviously leave the correct count the way it is. the way it is now is that if the question was attempted and wrong the correct count shouldn't be updated (that's good)

Comment: Updated it, and if you don't need the count of attempts, you can rather use a boolean and call it something like `firstTry`, and only add correct or wrong if its first try. When wrong, set `firstTry` to false, and reset `firstTry` to true when user enter a correct answer.